# Free "on-screen keyboard" software with feature of changing font

Tags: linux, open-source, virtual-keyboard

I am looking for [Free](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) on-screen keyboard [software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) for GNU/Linux that provides feature of changing font.

I know there is [`onboard`](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-osk.html.en) available but I can't find any setting for changing font in preferences. Though it has ability to choose custom-layout but I've to make it.

---

Something like: On windows, the on-screen keyboard has this option:
[image: screenshot1]

So-that I can set font and watch new layout:
[image: screenshot2]

As explained **if I've fonts of another/different language than it is very useful to work by means of this layout according to font!**

Note: this is not actually changing language or input-sources but only fonts

---

So, **I am looking for FOSS that provides feature of changing fonts.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Florence](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html) is an extensible free on-screen keyboard, which allows you to change fonts.

[image: Florence keyboard]

To change settings (including fonts), click at the "tool" key on the left side (1st column) of the keyboard. Then you may change fonts at the "Style" tab in settings.

[image: font-setting]

Comment: Your First post on Software Recommendation helped